# How to check the login using jquery post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a login test application using jquery post, php ..
It is reading the value but not sending the data to server.php and returning the data.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="contact-form pad-25">
    <div class="subpage-title">
    <h5>Please Login</h5>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Pass" type="text" id="pass" name="password" style="display:none">
       </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-flat flat-color btn-rounded" id="next_name">NEXT</a>
<button class="btn btn-flat flat-color btn-rounded" type="submit" id="submit" style="display:none">Submit</button>
<div>
   <!-- row-fluid -->                                    
</div>
```

//SCRIPT

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#next_name").click(function(){
                $("#fname").hide('slow');
                    $("#pass").show('fast');
                    $("#next_name").hide();
                    $("#submit").show();
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                        var r=confirm("Login Confirmaition!!")
                        if(r==true)
                        {
                            //alert("asd");
                            var pass=$("#pass").val();
                            var fname=$("#fname").val();
                            alert(pass);
                            alert(fname);
                            $.post('server.php', {fname:fname, pass:pass, type:'passwordcheck'}, function(msg){
                                    alert(msg);
                                });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE**
I tried to dump the data but the application is not reaching the server.php at all

```
  <?php 
//echo "asdasd";
$type=$_POST['type'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
//var_dump($fname);
$data = '{"name":"Pramit", "password":"Pramit123"}';
if($type=='passwordcheck'){
            $phpdata = json_decode($data);
            if($phpdata->name == $fname && $phpdata->password == $pass)
            {
                echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "fail";
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: What is the response of the AJAX request, 500?

Comment: Please check AJAX file url/path in jquery post. In your server.php write echo "<pre>"; print_r($_REQUEST); exit; to check what variable you get. Use firebug in FF to check for AJAX request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, you have an error.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#next_name").click(function(){
                $("#fname").hide('slow');
                    $("#pass").show('fast');
                    $("#next_name").hide();
                    $("#submit").show();
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                        var r=confirm("Login Confirmaition!!")
                        if(r==true)
                        {
                            pass=$("#pass").val();
                            fname=$("#fname").val();
                            //$.post('/server.php', {fname:fname, pass:pass, type:'passwordcheck'}, function(msg){
                            $.post('http://localhost/server.php', {fname:$fname, pass:$pass, type:'passwordcheck'}, function(msg){
                                    alert(msg);
                                });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

If you are in the same server where are you doing the request, you haven't got to insert the server, but if you put the server, i recommend you to put at least the protocol, because that request is doing on http://localhost/localhost/server.php, thats why you can't see the receive in the server part.

Remember too that in Javascript, variables are written like that:

```
var variable1;
variable = variable1;
```

**Never** put the variables like PHP, using the $ symbol

Tell me if that is useful to you :D

Comment: **Never use like PHP and $**. Why? Can you explain? One can use it, if you heard about `jquery`.

Comment: One thing is use $. or $( and other is $var

Comment: thanks updated the code but error seems in server side json data.. ;

Comment: If you are using Firefox or Chrome, open the F11 view (perfect for devs). Go "network" tab and click the button. That must give you a new line (at least one). If it is a 200 number, client server, it throws a 3xx error, server error.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wrong `url` you must add `http://` in your post url like,

```
 $.post('http://localhost/server.php'...
```